# Error: 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable is set to non-existent path

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Error: 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable is set to non-existent path: /root/android-sdk-linux
Try update it manually to point to valid SDK directory.

Comment: That error message is pretty self-explaining, imho. What did you already try to solve this?

Comment: Also, you should take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Access to root folder is restricted, move the Sdk to another place.

Answer (score 1):

Access to root folder is restricted.

Change the Sdk folder from /root/Android/Sdk to somewhere else. I chose /etc/Android/Sdk

```
sudo su
mv /root/Android /etc
```

Change permission

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /etc/Android
```

Then correct the path in .bashrc

```
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc
```

At the begining of the file add lines

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/etc/Android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

**Check for any duplicate export statements for ANDROID_HOME, If found remove them.**

Save and close .bashsrc , then source .bashrc

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Close all open terminals. Open a fresh terminal and try your Android Sdk dependent commands.